# Python Numpy One Hot to Regions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, one-hot-encoding

What is the best way to make this One Hot encoded matrix

```
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]])
```

as

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

In other words, how to decode One Hot array?

Comment: Can you please explain what's the logic behind this? what do you mean by 'decode'?

Comment: @kmario23 reverse operation of One Hot encoding. This question is already answered below.

Comment: I wrote a matrix, which was encoded to One Hot, and a second matrix below, which was reversed back from One Hot. I've just needed code  to do this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.argmax` along `axis=2` -

```
a.argmax(2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [186]: a
Out[186]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]])

In [187]: a.argmax(2)
Out[187]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: There might be something faster... argmax can't stop early when it hits the index.

Comment: argmax is special cased to stop at the first true for boolean arrays, but I don't think that will kick for an integer array. But if you have to convert to bool anyway it's probably a wash.